# Let r and a be two distinct elements of group G such that $r^4=a^2=1$ and $ara^{-1}=r^{-1}$ . Let $<a,r>$ denote the subgroup generated by a and r

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $r$ and $a$ be two distinct elements of group G such that $r^4=a^2=1$ and $ara^{-1}=r^{-1}$ . Let $\langle a,r\rangle$ denote the subgroup generated by $a$ and $r$

what are the conjugacy classes and what are normal subgroups? :

as i know that this group of order $8$ is i am right? i stuck from here can any help

Comment: In the plane think of $a$ as reflection over the $x$ axis and $r$ as rotation by 90 degrees. You have the symmetry group of the square. Maybe this geometric intuition will help you along the way

Comment: You do not know that the group has order $8$. You said that $a$ and $r$ are distinct, but $a$ could be the identity and $r$ could have order $2$. From the information given, the group could have order $2$, $4$ or $8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is group of order $8$ which can be written as $G=\{1,r,r^2,r^3,a,ra,r^2a,r^3a\}$

The conjugacy classes are $$(1)=\{1\},(r)=\{r,r^3\},(r^2)=\{r^2\},(a)=\{a,r^2a\},(ra)=\{ra,r^3a\}$$

For an element $x\in G$, $(x)=\{gxg^{-1}\;|\;g\in G\}$. And also, $|(x)|$ divides the order of $G$. So these two facts might help you to get the above answers.

The normal subgroups are $$\{1\},G,\{1,r^2\}(\text{which is $Z(G)$}),\{1,r,r^2,r^3\},\{1,r^2,a,r^2a\},\{1,r^2,ra,r^3a\}$$

You can first find the possible subgroups and determine which of them are normal using definition. Also, it might be helpful if you know that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, if $[G:H]=2$, then $H$ must be normal.

Note: The group in your question is actually Dihedral group of order $8$. You can try search it to get more about its properties.

Comment: You have omitted one subgroup

Comment: @learnmore Added. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: Also, it does not follow from the information given that the group has order $8$. It could have order $2$ or $4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is it because $r^4=1$ does not imply $|r|=4$ right? So is there enough information to find the conjugacy classes and normal subgroups?

Comment: I would guess that the intention was to assume that $r$ has order $4$ and that $a$ has order $2$, and then your answer is correct. But yes, just saying $r^4=1$ only tells you that $r$ has order $1$, $2$ or $4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt One personal question : Why the presentation for dihedral group is normally written as $\langle x^4=y^2=1,xy=yx^{-1}\rangle$ and not  $\langle |x|=4,|y|=2,xy=yx^{-1}\rangle$?

Comment: The standard  notation for a group presentation is $\langle x,y \mid x^4=y^2=1, xy=yx^{-1} \rangle$. This has a well-defined meaning. In general, a relation $x^n=1$ does not imply that $x$ has order $n$. For a simple example, consider the presentation $\langle x \mid x^4=x^6=1 \rangle$, in which $x$ has order $2$.